# How to sort the sender's names in inbox?

Tags: message, whatsapp, inbox, columnsorting

I want to sort an inbox by the sender's name.

I have the following MySQL query I am using to sort:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM Msg_Tab 
  ORDER BY uid DESC
) AS searchmsg 
GROUP BY sender;
```

But, here it's not sorting if I send any message.
It's only sorting while I'm receiving messages.

**MySQL table** : `Msg_Tab`

**Columns**: `sender`, `receiver`, `time`, `message`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Msg_Tab ORDER BY uid DESC) as searchmsg group by sender;

Answer (score 0):

You must sort by the `sender`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM Msg_Tab 
  ORDER BY uid DESC
) AS searchmsg 
GROUP BY sender
ORDER BY sender;
```